# [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - where am I doing this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

I'm trying to paginate my events index page using below in my middleware.js file

```
function paginatedResults(Event) { return async (req, res, next) => {
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page);
    const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit);

    const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
    const endIndex = page * limit;

    const results = {}

    if(endIndex < await Event.countDocuments().exec()) {
        results.next = {
            page: page + 1,
            limit: limit
        }
    }

    if(startIndex > 0) {
        results.previous = {
            page: page - 1,
            limit: limit
        }
    }

    results.results = await Event.find().limit(limit).skip(startIndex).exec()
    res.paginatedResults = results;
    console.log(results);
    }
}
```

Here's my router:

```
router.route('/')
    .get(catchAsync (events.index))
```

And here's the controller function where I'm receiving the error for passing the headers twice:

```
module.exports.index = async (req, res) => {
    const events = await Event.find({}).populate('artist');
    res.json(res.paginatedResults);
    res.render('events/index', { events })
};
```

The `console.log(results)` line in my pagination middleware function works just fine -- it returns the proper array. But how do I display that array on my index.js?

Also, my index.js iterates over the `events` data passed from the controller function, so I'd like to use the same variable name so I don't have to refresh my client code below:

```
<% for (let event of events){%>
    <div class="card mb-3 shadow">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <% if( (Date.parse(Date().toString()) > Date.parse(event.event_start)) && (Date.parse(Date().toString()) < Date.parse(event.event_end))) { %>
                    <h5 class="card-title mb-2"><a href="/events/<%= event.id %>"><%= event.event_name %></a>
                        <span>
                            <a href="/events/<%= event.id %>/prompt" class="badge bg-success">Check in</a></span>
                        </h5>
                    <p class="mb-1 mt-1">Artist: <a href="/artists/<%=event.artist.id%>/"><%= event.artist.username %></a>
                        </p>
                    <p class="text mt-1">Date: <%= event.event_start %> </p>
                    <p class="tetext mt-1xt">Venue: <%= event.venue_name %> </p>
                    <p class="text mt-1">
                        <small class="text-muted"><%= event.description %> </small>
                    </p>

                    <% } else { %> 
                    <h5 class="card-title mb-2"><a href="/events/<%= event.id %>"><%= event.event_name %></a>
                        </h5>
                    <p class="mb-1 mt-1">Artist: <a href="/artists/<%=event.artist.id%>/"><%= event.artist.username %></a>
                        </p>
                    <p class="text mt-1">Date: <%= event.event_start %> </p>
                    <p class="text mt-1">Venue: <%= event.venue_name %> </p>
                    <p class="text mt-1">
                        <small class="text-muted"><%= event.description %> </small>
                    </p>
                    <% } %> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% }%>
```

Help me, Obi-wan Kenobi..

Comment: you're doing both `res.json` and `res.render` - you can only send one response

Answer (score 0):

You can send a res only once So you have to send json along with the view in order to avoid this error.

Comment: Hi @jenil Narola - can you clarify what you mean with code, please? I'm not following when you say "send json along with the view."

Comment: @econobro By providing code you are sending a response to js file 2 times. First as a JSON and second as a view but in nodeJS lifecycle, you have to send only one response like this

 `res.render('events/index', { events,paginatedResult })`

Comment: I removed `res.json(res.paginatedResults);` and added your code and receive error `ReferenceError: paginatedResult is not defined`. Any ideas?

Comment: @econobro from paginatedResults function please just return the result like

`res.paginatedResults = results;
return results`

then from module.exports please add these line

`let paginatedResult=paginatedResults()
res.render('events/index', { events,paginatedResult })`

Comment: Still receiving the same error. I'm going to try a different route unless you have other ideas. Appreciate you trying.